# How can running compiled code or script in nginx

Tags: linux, bash, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

`exec_push /usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localho ...`
 this code running but

`exec_push /usr/bin/output`

`exec /usr/bin/output`

`exec /usr/bin/test.sh`

these codes do not work, but the same codes work on the terminal. why?

they are in there I moved. permissions are full and the owners are root.

Comment: "these codes do not work" is not a problem description with which we can help you. If you got the error message, then add this error message to the question post.

Comment: There is no error output, nginx usually does not fail in such operations.                 ` exec_push /usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localhost:1935/$app/$name -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -g 10 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/$name_hi      I am trying to run the following instead of this command.  (exec /usr/bin/output)

Comment: Still we can only guess what is going on. We don't know the content of `/usr/bin/test.sh` script and `/usr/bin/output` executable.

Comment: problem files, problem how to run compiled code and script in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

you can use shell_exec instead or if it's not working use can check the function is enable or not !

check php.ini

or use the following codes to ensure

`<?php`
 $function_name = "exec";
    if ( function_exists($function_name) ) {
        echo "$function_name is enabled";
    }
 else {
        echo "$function_name is not enabled";
    }
`?>`